# Derivative using power rule?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I'm learning Calculus and I don't know how the solution is wrong, I'm trying the below:
$$f(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 5t^{2}}} \ \rightarrow \ (1+5t^2)^\frac{-1}{2} $$ 
I know I should use a combination of the power and chain rule:
$$f'(t) = -\frac{1}{2}(1+5t^2)^\frac{-3}{2} \times 10t$$
This is where I'm stuck

Here is the correct solution, and I don't understand how they got it:
$$f'(t) = -\frac{5t}{ (5t^{2} + 1)^\frac{3}{2} } \ $$

***UPDATE:***
They simplified, had a moment there thanks!

Comment: That's it. You're done!

Comment: Nvm just saw my trivial mistake thanks!

Comment: Your solution is equal to the correct solution and therefore it is correct.

Comment: @craz1001 Minor point but you've got a function of $x$ on the left-side but a function of $t$ on the right-side.

Comment: Glad you found your mistake. Now please delete the question, since leaving it here will probably not help anyone else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could use the quotient rule: the derivative of the numerator times the denominator minus the numerator times the derivative of the denominator all divided by the denominator squared.

$$f'(t) = \frac{0 - 1\cdot(-\frac{1}{2}(1+5t^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot 10t}{1+5t^2} = \frac{-5t}{(1+5t^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$